# sql access to rows inside ongoing transaction

Tags: sql, transactions

I have the next question. Lets imagine during transaction I insert row into *projects* table and inside the same transaction I want to access this row, should it be in table or only after transaction?

Comment: It should be in the table as seen from within the transaction.  It should not be visible outside the transaction.

Comment: Depends on set transaction changes visible/invisible, if you can see it or not. (Other transactions can't.)

Comment: jarlh, what do you mean by "set transaction changes visible/invisible"?